# Filling/hollowing between two solid objects

Tags: modifiers

I have two objects (with solid modifiers applied) one is a shirt, the other a body.
These will ultimately be 3D printed in various forms. The below image is a temporary intersection Boolean across both objects (just for explanation in this post). There are holes internally, lots of wasted polygons. How do you 'fill these gaps'? Essentially remove the faces that are internal and therefore redundant.

Essentially, consider a hand in a fingerless glove, the hand is a solid closed object, the glove a solid wrapper. With the hand in the glove the polygons of the hand inside the glove is redundant, the internal surface of the glove is equally redundant as the glove is watertight between the fingers and the wrist.

The internal empty volume is enclosed, no gaps, in 2D they would be considered as islands inside a polygon. I've tried boolean operators, union, merging [CTRL+J], remove internal faces [seems to be only for internal divisions?]

What procedure would I have to follow to achieve the desired result?

[image]